# Optimal coin position to win dice game (generalisation)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

I can't stop thinking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4659973/1107685) recent question:

> You have 3 coins and a die. There is a line with positions from 1 to 1000. you need to place the coins in any of these positions in the line. from position 0, you keep rolling the die and you jump that many steps in the line. if you reach any position with a coin in it, you win. If you cross 1000 without reaching any positions with a coin, you lose. What are the optimal positions to place the coins in the line to maximize your chance of winning the game?

The die is $6$ sided and fair. An obvious guess is that the coins should be placed at $4,5,6$, but there's no clear way to prove this by hand. @Joriki solved it with the observation that coins can't be placed more than $5$ apart, and a computer search, and indeed this is the best arrangement. This is good, but doesn't satiate me, as the problem seems very neat, so I want a generalisable solution. So I would like to know if this arrangement still works with $c$ coins and a $n$ sided die.

I.e. is the strategy of placing the coins at $n-c+1, \dots , n$ always optimal for any $c$ and $n$?

---

I haven't been able to make much progress, so this can be ignored, but here are my observations:

If we say $y_s$ is the probability of the die landing on position $s$, then $y$ satisfies a recurrence relation
$$y_s = \frac{1}{n}y_{s-1} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}y_{s-n}$$
This means we can find a formula for $y_s$ which looks like
$$y_s = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \lambda^s$$
Where $a_i$ are constants that are computed using the initial conditions and $\lambda_i$ are the roots of the auxilary equation
$$\lambda^n - \frac{1}{n}\lambda^{n-1} - \dots - \frac{1}{n}\lambda - \frac{1}{n} = 0$$

Let $x_1 , \dots x_c$ be the positions of the coins, then the probability of hitting any of them can be
$$P(X_1 \cup \dots \cup X_c) = \sum_{i=1}^c P(X_i) - \sum_{i<j} P(X_i \cap X_j) + \dots + (-1)^{c-2} \sum_{1 \le i_1 < \dots < i_{c-1} \le c} P(X_{i_1}) \cap \dots \cap P(X_{i_{c-1}}) + (-1)^{c-1} P(X_1 \cap \dots \cap X_c)$$
By the inclusion-exclusion principle. And the probability of any of the intersections can be computed as
$$P(X_{i_1} \cap \dots \cap X_{i_k}) = P(X_{i_1})\cdot P(X_{i_2}|X_{i_1}) \cdot \dots \cdot P(X_{i_k}|X_{i_{k-1}})$$
Where, because the die roll is autonomous, $P(X_j|X_i)$ is just the probability $y_s$ of landing on square $s$ where $s = x_j - x_i$

So we can in  principle substitute all this in to get a massive unwieldy formula for the probability of winning with a given combination of coin positions. However, the formula doesn't seem to lend itself to discrete maximisation. When written in terms of $y_s$ it looks symmetric enough that there might be a nice way to simplify it, but I don't know it.

Comment: Well, one natural guess is that you fill the "back end" of the first $d$ slots with all the coins. Have you found any example in which that's not the answer?

Comment: @lulu I haven't found any such example. Solving any case except $c=1$ by hand seems difficult

Comment: Well, if $c=2$ is impossible, I don't think much of one's chances in general.  But of course, you don't actually need to "solve" it, you can just try a few patterns.  Any particular pattern is easy to compute with and I'm reasonably certain that the  answer will be close to what I said.

Comment: Abstractly, it seems easy to argue that there is no advantage in placing any coin outside the first $d$, so all you need to argue is that there is no advantage in leaving any gaps in the coin sequence.  To be sure, I might have that last bit wrong, but any counterexample would be very informative.

Comment: I don't think using that characteristic polynomial will get us anywhere, as it has either $1$ or $2$ roots, not $n$ roots. It's clear to prove without anything complex that for $c=1$, the best position is $n$. I'm trying to figure this out by treating the coins individually, and I think that might help.

Comment: Right, it's late, and I've done a lot of this by hand, so take this with a grain of salt, but: I believe the expected pattern breaks just after the situation presented in the original question. If we want to place *four* coins on the path using a d$6$, the first three go at positions $4,5,6$, but the fourth goes at position $11$. I'm confident but not yet certain, but I'm certain that you can't do this by recursion. We have to ask, for each position $p$, "how many ordered tuples with $p$ or fewer members add up to $p$?" Longer answer tomorrow.

Comment: Hmmm. I stand/sit corrected and also confused. The probability of landing on set of positions is not directly correlated (just) to the probabilities of landing on each of the positions, separately. I didn't expect it to just be the sum, obviously, but I didn't expect the stark difference. Using a d$6$, The positions with the highest chance of being landed on are $6,5,11,12,10,16$. Landing on $4$ is well below average. But putting coins on $4,5,6$ has about an $80\%$ win rate, and $5,6,11$ gets only a $70\%$ win rate. I'm highly confused.

Comment: $p(4)=0.2647, p(5)=0.3088, p(6)=0.3602, p(11)=0.2934$, but $p(4,5,6)=0.79, p(5,6,11)=0.70$ (these are simulated, the ones for a single position are calculated, as I can't yet figure out a calculation for them). $\lim_{z \to \infty} p(z) = 2/7$, and it appears to be $2/(d+1)$ for other sizes of die.

Comment: Regarding to the $2/(d+1)$ limit see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3906174/573047). Maybe the method there can be used to answer the question here completely.

Comment: @BillyJoe I actually realized at some point after post that, yeah, $2/7$ makes sense just informally because your average roll on a d$6$ is $7/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : As Zoe Allen pointed below, this argument is wrong as this greedy placement does not take into account the reduction of hitting probability..

---

I am thinking something along this line. First, we will prove that there is an optimal placement that contains $n$. Given this condition, we show that there is an optimal placement which contains $\{n,n-1\}$, and so on until you run out of coins.

---

So to prove that there is an optimal placement that contains $n$.

Let me write $H(x; \{y_1, \dots, y_k\})$ to denote the probability of hitting $x$ given that we already put other coins on $\{y_1,\dots,y_k\}$, lets just assume that it is equal to $0$ if $x$ is in $\{y_1,\dots,y_k\}$.
Consider an optimal placement $\{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_c\}$, an oracle told you a part of this optimal placement but it omits the last coin, i.e., $\{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}$.

If the partial placement that the oracle told you already contains $n$, then we are done.

If it is not, then we notice that we must have $H(y^*_c; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}) = \max_x H(x; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$.

We have that $H(x;\{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$ is an increasing function of $x$ for $x$ in $[1,\dots,n]$ except when $x$ is in $\{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}$. So in this region, $n$ is the maximizer.

Next, we can show that $H(x; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}) \leq H(n; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$ for $x > n$.  To show this, we notice that in this region $H(x; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$ is essentially an average of the previous $c$ values.

Hence, $H(n+1; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}) \leq H(n; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$ as we previously assert that this is an increasing function on $[1,...,n]$. You then simply do induction to show it for all $x >n$.

So we have that $H(n; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}) = \max_x H(x; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$. In other words, there is an optimal placement which contains $n$.

---

Now to show that there is an optimal placement that contains $\{n,n-1\}$.

We repeat the same step, but I put a constrain that the oracle can only told me the a partial placement of the form $\{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}$ with $y^*_1 = n$. A partial placement of this form must exists by our previous argument.

We see that this is an increasing function on $[1,...,n-1]$ and $H(x;\{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}) \leq H(n-1;\{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$ for $x > n$.
So now we know that there exists an optimal placement which contains $\{n,n-1\}$.

---

You basically can repeat the argument until you have an optimal placement of the form $\{n-c+1, \dots, n\}$. What we are doing here is basically some form of greedy algorithm. I bet there is a cleaner proof using some matroid argument, but nothing comes up to me right now.

Comment: I don't think we need to have $H(y^*_c; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\}) = \max_x H(x; \{y^*_1, \dots, y^*_{c-1}\})$. That holds if we know that $y_c^{*}$ is the last coin, but otherwise its placement affects the chances of other coins getting hit, so that the best setup for all the coins isn't necessarily the one that maximises the chance of $y_c^{*}$ getting hit individually.

Comment: You are definitely right, I overlooked that part! Thanks